# Regex to match several groups of a-zA-Z0-9- but not 2 consecutive underscores __

Tags: regex

I've got a couple of strings, usually words and letter, upper and lower case, mixed with numbers. I'd like to match them all unless there are two consecutive underscores in the string. Examples of my strings:

```
first-string-String-71-word
second-otherword-X-17-word-last-word
third-nextword-8-word__otherword
```

Now I'm searching for a regex which matches the first and second but not the third.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) 
(?!__)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
([a-zA-Z0-9-^(__)]+)
```

Those seem to be all not working - what's the right approach here?

https://regex101.com/r/i7AnSS/1

Comment: do you want to match single underscores?

Comment: do you have exactly one string per line, no spaces? or you have something like "sentences"?

Comment: For your example strings where the words are separated by a hyphen, try `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqFBG8/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a negative lookahead for two consecutive `_` in the string. Note that you need to anchor the regex to the start and end of the string, otherwise it can match from partway through.

```
^(?!.*?__)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/i7AnSS/3

Note that this assumes your strings *are* allowed to have a single `_` in them. If that is not the case, the simple

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
```

will exclude any strings with `_` in them.

Comment: Perhaps `\b` instead of `^`/`$` is a bit more flexible?

Comment: @jhnc the only question about using `\b` is that it can match `-` if it occurs at the beginning or end of the string. I'm not sure if that would be an issue or not.

Comment: That negative look ahead is redundant if the accepted character set does not contain an underscore.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi you're right, if the string is anchored at both ends it is indeed redundant unless OP wants to match `_`. If he doesn't (wait to see the reply to the comment on the question) I'll delete.

Comment: @Nick: No buddy you don't have to delete your answer. That was just my quick observation so thought of notifying you. Indeed OP's post isn't clear whether he wants to match whole input or wants to filter such words containing double underscores, which implicitly means he should allow single underscores.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi without the negative lookahead it doesn't add anything to the other posted answer. No point having two the same. Anyway, we'll see what OP says

Comment: @Nick: My guess is he wants to allow single underscores which he missed to state else otherwise he could have simply said to not allow any underscores at all and in that case your regex would just need underscore in your character set.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I've added a note to the answer (and updated the initial regex) to cover the single `_` situation. Thanks for the input.

Comment: So far, I haven't come across a string with a single underscore - so it is indeed only for the ones with __ (two underscores).
Thanks for the elaboration on it - still learning regex and it helps me understand things better.

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
```

and Check it on Url https://regex101.com/r/u82mre/1